# Possible to extract size of spaces in a PDF

Tags: pdf, latex, pymupdf

Suppose customized spacing is used in LaTex as exemplified below when generating a PDF. Is there a way to extract the sizes of whitespaces from the PDF? I have tried `pymupdf`, but it does not give info about size of whitespaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Define custom spacing commands
\newcommand{\widespace}{\hspace{0.6em}}
\newcommand{\narrowspace}{\hspace{0.4em}}

\begin{document}

Hello,\widespace{}world!\narrowspace{}This\widespace{}is\narrowspace{}a\widespace{}simple\narrowspace{}LaTeX\widespace{}example.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/t/LSt1DPeBbWj5ACZ9) is the compiled PDF.

Comment: I have update the LaTex, now should be consistent with the PDF.

Comment: How did u get the raw PDF data?

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is no. I ran it through MathPix which didn't detect it, but the better reason is this: I opened your PDF in Acrobat and measured the space between the comma and the word "world" which comes out to 0.08 inches (sorry, not sure why Acrobat doesn't use something more scientific than inches...). From your code, the space should have been `0.6em` which should be 0.6*1.666666 in = 0.1 inches. So even if you did have a software measuring this for you, your LaTeX output doesn't seem to follow your code to begin with and until you fix that I don't know how you would recover something like this correctly.
[image: Adobe screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @KJ, I didn't realize the definition of `em` was this intricate. I just googled the em-to-inch conversion. That notwithstanding, it would still seem pretty challenging to read out this length from the PDF as this doesn't seem to be stored within the PDF.

Comment: I had no idea. That's interesting! Can you think of a way for @sinoTrinity to extract this info from a PDF and post an answer based on this?